# dart get object value in array of array

Tags: dart

```
main() {
  var i = [{"name" : "123", "item":[{"name": "ssr", "obj":[{"name":"2", "uri": null}]}]}];
 print(i[0]["item"]);
 //i[0]["item"]["name"] doesn't work!
}
```

I want to get the value of name of i[0]["item"] and "name" in "obj". how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
main() {
  var i = [
    {
      "name": "123",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "ssr",
          "obj": [
            {"name": "2", "uri": null}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  var list = i[0]["item"] as List;
  print(list[0]["name"]); // ssr
}
```